# Configure ESLint to parse .ts and .tsx as Typescript and .js and .jsx as Ecmascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have installed typescript to use in my Create React App project. I want to gradually refactor the ES files to TS.

But the linter now also parses the .js and .jsx files as Typescript.

```
/project/file.js
  19:35  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
  20:35  warning  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

Is it possible to parse the .js and .jsx files as Ecmascript and the .ts and .tsx as Typescript?

My configuration is:

**./eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts"] }],
  }
}
```

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The command used to run:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext=.jsx,.js,.tsx,.ts  ."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ah, you should use the overrides property in eslint.rc [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597142/how-to-run-typescript-eslint-on-ts-files-and-eslint-on-js-files-in-the-same-pr).

```
"overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
      ],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]
    }
  ]
```

Then I noticed that the ES files that included TS weren't finding the .ts files:

```
/project/file.js
  3:26  error  Unable to resolve path to module './AnotherComonent' import/no-unresolved
  3:26  error  Missing file extension for "./AnotherComonent"       import/extensions
```

Can be resolved by either ([source](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1615#issuecomment-579666755)) adding this to **.eslintrc**(recommended):

```
{
  "extends": ["plugin:import/typescript"],
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
}
```

Or ([source](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1180) and [source](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1568#issuecomment-564687683)):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In other words, add the resolver for the file manually.

And ignore the im/extensions error. Not ideal but it seems to be the only way at the time of writing.

Comment: There seems to be errors in this. You talk about adding code upon code. Plus there is an extra comma at the end of you Jason recommendation.

Comment: Feel free to propose edits. And adding 'code upon code' is exactly the point of that blogpost. Sometimes you can't swap language settings in an entire codebase. Perfectly fine that you are critical but add information on why you would do it differently. (seem* since the subject is plural, and it's JSON, not JASON)

Comment: I was expecting you to make a good clarification and you did. I wasn't being a critic as such. Its good what you did. I just think people that are really new would still struggle to implement your suggestion. Thats not really your fault. Its hard in general. Linting has been harder than writing the code in the first place a lot of the time.