# Can .js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx be used simultaneously in a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have a React project created using JS only. react-scripts version: 5.0.0.
Now, I want to start using TS in the project (and slowly migrate the project overtime). It's quite a huge project now and everything can't be migrated all at once. Thus I want to start adding new components (or pages) written in TypeScript and also gradually work on migrating the existing JavaScript files to TypeScript.

I googled for solution, and answers suggested to create a new TS project and copy the files to the new project after renaming them to .ts or .tsx. But in our case, it's not very feasible.

Other answers suggested ejecting. But I want to use that if all other ways fail.

Are there any other ways I can do this? If we could somehow allow to have both the type of files and then could disable this in future when all the files have been migrated.

Currently trying to import a .tsx file in .js says "module not found". I tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62953124/10951873). But still has the same error.

Comment: Definitely eject. If you’re managing a large project, you need to know your build tool anyway in the long run. Now is opportunity to get started.

Comment: JavaScript is a valid subset of TypeScript. Rename all your files to their TS equivalent and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Answers with no explanation are rarely useful and therefore frequently downvoted. Explain what changes you made and why/how they helped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).